# Filter the JSON object and write the results in the local .json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've fetched an API and got a JSON object that I need to filter through and store in a new local json file.

the results get returned, but I can't figure out a way to filter through the json file (data) and correctly write it into the new newfile.json file.

```
 .then(
      json => { 
        const data = JSON.stringify(json)
        const filtered = data.map( //some filter function )
        fs.writeFile('src/data/newfile.json', filtered, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
```

Here is the example of the json data I'm getting from the array of surveys.

```
{
        "surveyId": 515315,
        "reviewId": "34152",
        "transactionInfo": {
          "transactionRef": "1806001511991",

          "transactionCity": "Plymouth",
          "transactionState": "MN",
          "transactionType": null,
          "customerFirstName": "Kristine",
        },
        "serviceProviderInfo": {
          "serviceProviderName": "Lobster",
          "serviceProviderEmail": "lobster@bayeq.com",
          "serviceProviderId": 43346,
          "serviceProviderOfficeName": "Oakdale - 30152501",
          "serviceProviderRegionName": "Minnesota - Chacich",
          "serviceProviderOfficeId": 721581,
          "serviceProviderRegionId": 151563
        },
        "review": {
          "source": "encompass",
          "rating": "5.0",
          "summary": null,
          "description": "He was fantastic ",
          "agreedToShare": true,
          "verifiedCustomer": true,
          "retakeSurvey": false,
          "surveyResponses": [
            {
              "question": "How would you rate the service and support you received?",
              "type": "Numeric",
              "answer": "5"
            },
            {
              "question": "Please rate the level of advice and communication you received from [name].",
              "type": "Numeric",
              "answer": "5"
            },
            {
              "question": "How likely are you to refer friends and family to [name]?",
              "type": "Numeric",
              "answer": "10"
            },
            {
              "question": "How would you rate your overall experience?",
              "type": "Experience",
              "answer": "Great"
            }
          ],
          "reportedAbusive": false
        },
        "reviewStatus": "completed"
      }
```

How do I filter through this and create a new JSON file with the structure like

```
{
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "rating": 4.56,
    "testimonials": [{
        "description": "Fugiat ut sed occaecat.",
        "firstname": "Bob",
        "city": "Bananatown",
        "state": "TH"
    }]
}
```

Comment: The data in your expected output can be found nowhere in the input you pasted. Can you please elaborate a little more on how the transformation takes place? Perhaps post a more meaningful subset of your data and a *corresponding* expected output?

Comment: what is the js used for dat fetching like jqury or angular or other

Answer (score 0):

Here I used jquery

```js
var datat = {
            "surveyId": 515315,
            "reviewId": "34152",
            "transactionInfo": {
                "transactionRef": "1806001511991",

                "transactionCity": "Plymouth",
                "transactionState": "MN",
                "transactionType": null,
                "customerFirstName": "Kristine",
            },
            "serviceProviderInfo": {
                "serviceProviderName": "Lobster",
                "serviceProviderEmail": "lobster@bayeq.com",
                "serviceProviderId": 43346,
                "serviceProviderOfficeName": "Oakdale - 30152501",
                "serviceProviderRegionName": "Minnesota - Chacich",
                "serviceProviderOfficeId": 721581,
                "serviceProviderRegionId": 151563
            },
            "review": {
                "source": "encompass",
                "rating": "5.0",
                "summary": null,
                "description": "He was fantastic ",
                "agreedToShare": true,
                "verifiedCustomer": true,
                "retakeSurvey": false,
                "surveyResponses": [
                    {
                        "question": "How would you rate the service and support you received?",
                        "type": "Numeric",
                        "answer": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Please rate the level of advice and communication you received from [name].",
                        "type": "Numeric",
                        "answer": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "How likely are you to refer friends and family to [name]?",
                        "type": "Numeric",
                        "answer": "10"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "How would you rate your overall experience?",
                        "type": "Experience",
                        "answer": "Great"
                    }
                ],
                "reportedAbusive": false
            },
            "reviewStatus": "completed"
        };

        datat.review.surveyResponses = datat.review.surveyResponses.filter(function (a) {
            return a.answer === "10";
        });

        var sd = datat.review.surveyResponses[0].question;
        alert(sd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some guesses here. As has been pointed out, there are so many discrepancies between the sample input and sample output that readers don't have confidence in the mapping inferences that are available. The correlations I've relied upon are inconsistent with the structure of the sample output, but these are the only options that are even plausible.

---

Also, I think you probably don't want to stringify the incoming data. You want it to be an object, so you can directly address the data; if the data is coming in as a string, you need to parse it into an object with `JSON.parse`

---

Here's something that might work. I've chained `.then` calls to make it easier to insert new steps and reorder them if necessary. I've omitted any error handling, but if you're parsing strings that you receive from the internet, you'll want to have something that can handle the error that will be thrown when the input string isn't valid JSON.

```
.then(string => JSON.parse(string)) // only needed if your earlier promise returns a string
.then(json => ({
    email: json.serviceProviderInfo.serviceProviderEmail,
    rating: json.review.rating,
    testimonials: [{
        description: json.review.description,
        firstname: json.transactionInfo.customerFirstName,
        city: json.transactionInfo.transactionCity,
        state: json.transactionInfo.transactionState
    }]
}))
.then(summary => {
    return fs.writeFile('src/data/newfile.json', JSON.stringify(summary), 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
        return true
    })
})
```